# How to not reset the form on submit with `use:enhance` in Svelte?

Tags: forms, svelte, sveltekit, progressive-enhancement

I have a form that updates a product's information using a form with `use:enhance` and actions defined in `+page.server.ts` - However, whenever I submit the form, `use:enhance` resets the form elements and they all become blank, which is unexpected as the value for these elements is specified by `$page.data.product`, and the docs state that `use:enhance` runs `invalidateAll`.

Nonetheless, is there a way to stop this reset from occurring within the `use:enhance` function?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of [#7326](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/7326), you can pass a `reset: false` option to the `update` function in your `enhance` callback:

```html
<script>
  import { enhance } from '$app/forms';
</script>

<form
  method="POST"
  use:enhance={() => {
    return async ({ update }) => {
      update({ reset: false });
    };
  }}>
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Where are the API docs covering the `reset` argument?

Comment: Great question - as far as I could tell there weren't any yet, which is what made finding this feature particularly tricky :)

Answer (score 7):

If you return a function from the `use:enhance` action, that function will be called when you get a response from the form submit. This function in turn gets an `update` function which takes an option `reset` that you can give the value `false` to not reset the form:

```html
<script>
  import { enhance } from '$app/forms'
</script>

<form
  method="POST"
  use:enhance={() => {
    return async ({ update }) => {
      await update({ reset: false });
    };
  }}
>
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Where are the API docs covering the `reset` argument?

Comment: @AndreyMikhaylov-lolmaus https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#public-types-submitfunction - You can see it in the type definition of the `SubmitFunction` argument provided to `use:enhance` here